# Algorithm for extracting a language from DFA

Tags: java, algorithm

I am trying to find an algorithm to extract a language from a DFA. If that language is infinite then I only need to report up to :  `maxcount` <= 1000 strings. there are no restrictions on what order the are reported.

I have tried:(I don't know how to write algorithms so I just explain in words what I did)

a recursive algorithm - for each transition from one state to the next state/states save the transition character and then make a recursive call for each transition,if that transition was to an accepting state then report .if we have reached a "dead end" then there is noting to recurse on.

suppose the start state is `state 1` and there are two transitions to: `state 2` and `state 3` with transition characters `'a'`,`'b'` respectively. Then there is a transition from `state 3` to `state 4` with transition character `'c'`, only `state 4` is an accepting state.

going from `state 1` to `state 2` will give save  `'a'` as transition character , but since `state 2` is a dead end there will be noting to recurse on and since it is not an accepting state then there is noting to report.

Going from `state 1` to `state 3` will save  `'b'` and then go from `state 3` to `state 4`  will save `'c'` so that we have a total of `"bc"` and since `state 4` does not have any transitions the recursion ends. We report `"bc"` because `state 4` is an accepting state

---

If I have DFA with a loop - then in order to not get "stuck" in that loop I have made sure that "if" there is a another possible transition then we will always pick that transition and not the transition we made last time/times we where at that state ( a kind of memory for which transition we made at which states )

The algorithm works for small DFAs but it will give a Stack overflow on bigger DFA:s (imagine 20 transitions from `state 1` to `state 2` and 30 transitions  from `state 2` to `state 3`  and so on ).

Can anybody recommend more efficient algorithm?

Comment: Are you familiar with any graph algorithms? Graph search / connectivity algo are useful here.

Comment: Is your algorithm is like: finding all paths between start and accept state in DFA?

Comment: @djechlin I am not, but if you could elaborate on a specific algorithm that could help me I would be happy

Comment: A modified Dijkstra algorithm or DFS-with-trace, in which you accept revisiting a node/state at most K times for the nodes connected in a cycle (e.g. `(abc)*``). Start with K=1, get all the productions, if not enough, make K=2 and so on.

Comment: just look up graph search or connectivity algos.

Comment: @WasiAhmad well first of all there can be more than one  accepting state. Also remember that if it ever reaches an accepting state then it can go pass that and find yet another accepting state. So I guess thats more than finding "all paths" to an accepting state

Comment: @J.doe i agree but this is the beauty of graph traversal algorithms that you can modify them to serve your need :)

Answer (score 1):

1. Run a cycle detection algorithm.
2. If there are no cycles, run any path finding algorithm (BFS, DFS, Dijkstra, A*, etc) to list all paths from start to finish.
3. If there is a cycle run pathfinding to find a path from the start node to the cycle. Then output (start node to the cycle) + (the cycle starting at the connecting node) * N for N = 1,2,3,...,1000.

Alternately:

1. Convert to regex.
2. Generate words from regex.

Comment: Why would you need to worry about cycles? One possible answer is "because a DFS would never terminate if there is a cycle", which is true, but DFS is not the only way to skin a tree.

Comment: @rici there's a lot of answers to this question. Mine factors into easily google-able components.

Comment: does google help you with the question "what if the cycle you find has no accepting state?" :-) Of course, it's reasonably straightforward to fix the algorithm, although it won't be quite as tidy.

Answer (score 1):

I'd do this with a breadth-first search over the DFA, which will produce strings ordered by length.

Define an object consisting of a state and a string (there is a more memory-efficient solution here, but I think that if you only need to produce 1000 strings, this will be fine). Then create a work-queue of such objects. Initialize the workqueue with a single object whose state is the start state and whose string is empty.

Now repeat the following three steps until you have found `maxcount` strings or the queue becomes empty:

1. Remove the first object in the queue.
2. If its state is an accepting state, output its string.
3. For each possible out transition (which consists of a character and a new state), add to the end of the queue a new object with the transition's state and the concatenation of the object's string with the transition's character.

Comment: what do you mean by strings here? op wants to construct the grammar rules by traversing through the DFA graph. did you mean that?

Comment: @wasi: i don't believe that's what OP wants to construct; the word string comes straight from the question (normally I'd say "sentence" and "token" rather than "string" snd "character" but the algorithm is the same.)

Answer (score 1):

If you use a BFS, then cycles don't matter. The idea is to define search nodes that contain the current state and a pointer to the predecessor node. Therefore when you visit a node for an accepting state, you can trace the previous pointers backward to determine the accepted string (in reverse).  It turns out that its elegant if a search node also contains the character that caused the transition from the previous node's state to the current one.

Here's an approach in Java:

```
import java.util.ArrayDeque;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Deque;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Map.Entry;

class Experimental {
  // DFA state with its transitions, possibly accepting.
  static class State {
    final Map<Character, State> transitions = new HashMap<>();
    final boolean accept;    
    State(boolean accept) {
      this.accept = accept;
    }
  }

  // A little DFA.
  static final State s0 = new State(false);
  static final State s1 = new State(false);
  static final State s2 = new State(true);
  static final State s3 = new State(true);
  static {
    s0.transitions.put('a', s1);
    s0.transitions.put('b', s2);
    s0.transitions.put('c', s3);
    s1.transitions.put('d', s3);
    s2.transitions.put('e', s0);
    s2.transitions.put('f', s1);
  }

  // An enumerator of strings accepted by the DFA in order of length.
  static class Enumerator {
    static class Node {
      final Node prev;
      final char prevCh;
      final State state;
      Node(State start) {
        this(null, Character.MIN_VALUE, start);
      } 
      Node(Node prev, char ch, State state) {
        this.prev = prev;
        this.prevCh = ch;
        this.state = state;
      }
    }

    final Deque<Node> queue = new ArrayDeque<>();
    final List<String> output = new ArrayList<>();
    final State start;

    Enumerator(State start) {
      this.start = start;
    }

    Enumerator enumerate(int outputLimit) {
      queue.clear();
      output.clear();
      // Enqueue a search node for the start state.
      queue.add(new Node(start));
      while (!queue.isEmpty() && output.size() < outputLimit) {
        Node current = queue.pollFirst();
        if (current.state.accept) {
          // Follow prev pointers to build the accepted string.
          StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
          for (Node p = current; p.prev != null; p = p.prev) {
            sb.append(p.prevCh);
          }
          output.add(sb.reverse().toString());
        }
        // Enqueue nodes for the successors of current state.
        for (Entry<Character, State> transition : current.state.transitions.entrySet()) {
          queue.addLast(new Node(current, transition.getKey(), transition.getValue()));
        }
      }
      return this;
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(new Enumerator(s0).enumerate(20).output);
  }
}
```

Output:

```
[b, c, ad, beb, bec, bfd, bead, bebeb, bebec, bebfd, bebead, bebebeb, bebebec, bebebfd, bebebead, bebebebeb, bebebebec, bebebebfd, bebebebead, bebebebebeb]
```

Answer (score 0):

**Note**: I am guessing you can model this problem as finding all paths between start state and all accepting states. So, i believe this can be accomplished with a depth-first search of the graph. The depth-first search will find all non-cyclical paths between two nodes.

If you are familiar with [Depth First Search (DFS)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search) algorithm which is a graph search/traversal algorithm can be helpful in your problem. Let me give you a very simple example.

Given a directed graph, a source vertex ‘s’ and a destination vertex ‘d’, print all paths from given ‘s’ to ‘d’. Consider the following directed graph. Let the s be 2 and d be 3. There are 4 different paths from 2 to 3.

[image]

The idea is to do `Depth First Traversal` of given directed graph. Start the traversal from source. Keep storing the visited vertices in an array say `path[]`. If we reach the destination vertex, print contents of `path[]`. **The important thing** is to mark current vertices in `path[]` as visited also, so that the traversal doesn’t go in a cycle.

**Sample Code**: You can find a very simple code in `Java` [here](http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/45graph/AllPaths.java.html) to find all paths between two nodes in a graph.

Comment: For a typical DFA, the size of the set of sentences which do not involve a state repetition is likely to be *much* smaller than 1000, so it seems unlikely that this algorithm will return enough strings to meet the problem constraints.

Comment: I didn't get your point. You are saying DFS won't be able to generate the grammar rules by finding the paths between two nodes of a graph?

Comment: i don't find it obvious how you use a traversal through a DFA to produce a grammar, although I can see how to generate a sentence matched by the DFA. As I said to djechlin, though: why do you believe that the cycle even contains an accepting state? (Simple exanple: the DFA corresponding to the regular expression `ab*a`)